# Failure to transfer

Tags: java, maven

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/
maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has
elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-
plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):

```
Failed to transfer http://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-
 plugin-2.5.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required
```

Tried

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Maven requires https:

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/
```

Do you have a custom maven settings.xml ie ~/.m2/settings.xml. If so it may help to delete or change the name of this file as maven central has a default https url which you may be overriding.